# Opkix Studio Application

Tags: android

I am new here and came across a conundrum that I myself cannot solve.

I own an Opkix Camera system and their company went under maybe two years ago.

The app was removed from the Apple store and it still [lives on the Google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opkix.android&hl=en_US&gl=US), however, once downloaded you can't use the application because the login services do not work.

Does anyone know a way around this?

I've contacted the manufacturers but their email systems return errors and their phone systems are down.

I've tried to find where the login activity is called upon and manually change it to bypass login.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su].